# What is the "--" used with kubectl when running with minikube on Ubuntu?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I've been playing around with minikube on Ubuntu when I realized for any commands with options (e.g. -o yaml) to work, I need to do:

```
kubectl -- get pod my_test_pod -o yaml
```

while on Mac OS, I can simply do:

```
kubectl get pod my_test_pod -o yaml
```

I know on Linux, "--" means the end of options and whatever follows is treated as a param string. But I cannot understand why it is used here. Anyone can shed some light?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not standard. Check if `kubectl` is pointed at some weird wrapper script?

Comment: [Here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/kubectl/#synopsis) it said to used '-' but no reason explained

Comment: @Mahboob minikube has [`--` in code](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/6d763a1cc72aa0cc868c2afc99e44cc7fe5aa4a6/cmd/minikube/cmd/kubectl.go#L41), maybe just a  docco issue.  Probably that way because it is just a wrapper for "fetch and run kubectl"

Comment: @coderanger I'd guess it's pointed back at `minikube kubectl` somehow

Comment: @peidaqi How did you install minikube on Ubuntu?